# Different width and height from DisplayMetrics and $(window).width() in WebView

Tags: android, webview

Inside an Android app, I tried using the following way to obtain the screen width and height:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        final int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        final int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

This reports 1080 and 1920 respectively for my phone, which matches the specs.

However, inside a webview, when I used:

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
```

This reports only 360.

From this what I understand, both are using pixel as unit, so why are the values different?

Comment: Check your display scale, it probably equals 3

Comment: @RomanTruba where can I check that?

Comment: Is your webview constrained in any way, or are you displaying this webview in fullscreen?

Comment: @NoelBautista I am not sure about that. It is running fullscreen with all the default options I can find from tutorials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice width is same in both cases but units are different.

E.g.

**This is in Pixels**
metrics.widthPixels;

**This one is in Dps**
360 OR $(window).width();

**Convert 360Dps to pixels**

On xxhdpi device, 360dps = 1080px

[Dp to pixels & vice versa](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/)

Comment: I thought that the jQuery `.width()` would return `pixel` as in the actual pixels, but I guess you are right, it returns `dp` instead in a webview. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` method to obtain displayMetrics .

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
final int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
final int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple method (inside a utils class) to convert px <-> dp.

```
public static int convertIntToDp(int inputValue, DisplayMetrics displayMetrics){
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, inputValue, displayMetrics);
    }
```

I hope help you

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the dpi of your device belongs to **xxhdpi**

Where 300 dpi can be converted as *1080 pixels* width.
 [image: here]

and 640 dpi can be converted as *1920* pixels.

also you can include;

```
 private int convertDpToPixel(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, 
r.getDisplayMetrics());
    return (int) px;
}
```